# Colon breaks the bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DAR=$(ffprobe -v error -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries stream=display_aspect_ratio $1)
echo $DAR
if [ $DAR -eq 16:9 ]
then echo sixteen-by-nine
else
echo not-sixteen-by-nine
```

the result of the script is:

```
16:9
line 3: [: 16:9: integer expression expected
not-sixteen-by-nine
```

How can I safely use the string 16:9?

Comment: Use `man [` to get the manual on using if statements like that. Very useful for figuring out which one to use (-eq, = , etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `=` for string comparison (`-eq` is *only* for comparing integers, hence the error `integer expression expected`) and quote both values like `"$DAR"` and `"16:9"`:

```
if [ "$DAR" = "16:9" ]
```

Quoting is probably not strictly necessarily here, but considered to be "good practice" since sooner or later you'll have a string like `16 9` (with space) which will break stuff. Typically, you always want to quote strings to be on the safe side (I also find it easier to read since strings can now be syntax highlighted).